# Internal Error returned from Softlayer DNSManager API

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

We are using the Python 2.7 and the Python Softlayer 3.0.1 package and calling the `get_records` method on the `DNSManager` class. This is currently returning an `Internal Server` error:

```
2016-05-11T11:18:04.117406199Z Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-05-11T11:18:04.117715505Z File "/opt/**/**/***.py", line 745, in <module>
2016-05-11T11:18:04.117927757Z httpDnsRecords = dnsManager.get_records(httpDomainRecordId, data=dataspace, type="cname")
2016-05-11T11:18:04.118072183Z File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SoftLayer/managers/dns.py", line 152, in get_records
2016-05-11T11:18:04.118152705Z filter=_filter.to_dict(),
2016-05-11T11:18:04.118302389Z File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 347, in call_handler
2016-05-11T11:18:04.118398852Z return self(name, *args, **kwargs)
2016-05-11T11:18:04.118512777Z File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 316, in call
2016-05-11T11:18:04.118632422Z return self.client.call(self.name, name, *args, **kwargs)
2016-05-11T11:18:04.118814604Z File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SoftLayer/API.py", line 176, in call
2016-05-11T11:18:04.118907953Z timeout=self.timeout)
2016-05-11T11:18:04.118995360Z File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SoftLayer/transports.py", line 64, in make_xml_rpc_api_call
2016-05-11T11:18:04.119096993Z e.faultCode, e.faultString)
2016-05-11T11:18:04.119547899Z SoftLayer.exceptions.SoftLayerAPIError: SoftLayerAPIError(SOAP-ENV:Server): Internal Error
```

The httpDomainRecordId is the Id for the domain obtained from softlayer and dataspace is the string 'uk'.

Does anyone know why this would be returning an `Internal Error` from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely the error is due to the response contains a big amount of data, this error is documented [here](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/How-Solve-Error-fetching-http-headers), so you can try:

1.- Increase the timeout in the client.

2.- Add more filters in your request to limmit the result, currently your using datqa and type try adding host or ttl

3.- you can try using limits, but the manager does not provide that option. so you need to use API calls e.g.

```
import SoftLayer

client = SoftLayer.Client()

zoneId = 12345

objectMask = "id,expire,domainId,host,minimum,refresh,retry, mxPriority,ttl,type,data,responsiblePerson"

result = client['Dns_Domain'].getResourceRecords(id=zoneId, mask=objectMask, limit=200, offset=0)

print (result)
```

Comment: Thanks. the issue was indeed that the amount of data was to large and so was timing out on the server. Using your code sample to set the limits worked around this.